# Laravel 8: How to send validation response in JSON format using postman

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-8

I have this validation, how can I return an error response in postman?
please help guys.

```
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ];

    $validator = $this->validate($request, $rules);

    $data = $request->all();
```

Comment: You don't have to do anything, the framework already handles that. If the request fails validation, you will get an error response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

Then write validation like

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
          'message' => 'Invalid params passed', // the ,message you want to show
            'errors' => $validator->errors()
        ], 422);
    }
```